# Serial WriteLine in a Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to write code in C# that sends data from Serial to an Arduino every 2 seconds.

This is what I tried to do:

```
Thread sender = new Thread(voidSender);
public static void voidSender() {
  serialArduino.WriteLine("Test");
  Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

Comment: Your code is sending a string, waiting for 2 seconds and then the thread finishes. There is nothing that will repeat this. Use a loop or even better a timer

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are starting a thread running through the defined method, sending a single message. To send the message multiple times you need to add a loop to this method like

```
public void voidSender()
{
    //Send forever
    while(true)
    {
        serialArduino.WriteLine("Test");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

However, periodically events are typically done by using a timer. Simply initialize a timer like

```
System.Timers.Timer sendMessageTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
sendMessageTimer.Elapsed += OnSend;
sendMessageTimer.AutoReset = true;
sendMessageTimer.Enabled = true;
```

Inside the elapsed handler you can send the message like

```
private void OnSend(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    serialArduino.WriteLine("Test");
}
```

Comment: My biggest probrem is that I can't use .WriteLine in a static void :(

Answer (score -2):

Honestly I don't why you would mix open source platform such as Arduino with C# .net if its not running on core, but that's your concern not mine, I personally wouldn't do that.

if you want to send command every two seconds, I would advise you to use windows scheduler that's integrated in every windows system, however you can implement a clock on your own very easy, still why would you need to put such heavy load of 2 seconds timeframe when it will be almost notable by ordinary user. If you don't want to use clock based system you can use this modified example however it may throw stackoverflow exception sometime since its recursion and you must aways stay away from them if you plan to use this on the long run.

```
//First sorry for reusing your code but I am writing from my smartphone and 
//I am kind of lazy here is quick modification that would work but not the most clever way around
    Thread sender = new Thread(voidSender);
    public static void voidSender()
    {
        start:
        serialArduino.WriteLine("Test");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        goto start;
    }
```

Comment: There is zero recursion here, no stack overflows can happen. No reason to use goto here either. And rambling about open source and .NET doesn't help with the issue either. Not to mention running something every two seconds with Task Scheduler would be complete waste of resources compared to timing it inside an application. Not to mention usually applications do much more than just this.

Comment: Timing inside the application would be really hard to synchronize across serialization over two seconds, I have personally suffered this issue with timers and also there is that I am not braging about using .net and open source simple saying its not the best fit solution for such a small thing.Also this looks like console application which uses static members and if he decides to make it multithread he will suffer problems of overwriting local values due to the static members.This is why I went with the goto example, few lines of code and there is no need to be depended on timer since

Comment: Thread.Sleep already implements one of its own.There is also that timer would do the job for something that is based on longer period of synchronization however I can't see how it would fit in two seconds serialization to arduiono its just that timers tend to tick differently and can have slight delays from tick to tick. Also there is that if you create a time and set a delegate to fire an event once two seconds are passed its the same as going to the goto once the 2 seconds have passed on the sleep time and its even better because it wont allocate resource to count while its sleeping.

Comment: I think you have a lot of misunderstandings about things. There's no serialization here either. There's no resources allocated to count anything. Making a thread sleep is also setting a timer up to resume the thread afterwards. Also timers are more accurate than having a sleeping thread. Think about the difference for a moment.

Comment: Yes there is no serialization in timers, considering he is sending data to Arduino he will be seriliazing it toward the device since there is no other way. I do understand how timers work but I hardly see why he would need to implement one since threading is already implementing one and he is using thread already.In case his question was related toward creating a timer and sending the data to somewhere I would recommend timer but he is after all using Thread and creating timer and calling Thread.Sleep(2000) is the same in this case.

Comment: No, it's not the same. And there is no evidence about any serialization, just data transmission. And they don't need to implement one, just use one. It's already implemented in the framework. Terminology is important. And you did suggest using scheduler rather than a thread so why not a timer? In any case, not a place for a chat but I would suggest checking on things to avoid confusion.

Comment: As you raised the topic of Terminology cough, sending data over one device to another is called serialization and yes I do agree that its turning over a chat for which I am sorry and on the topic the very definition of recursions is a method or object that calls itself over and over so there is recursion in it. But I do agree that my suggestion for the scheduler was stupid however I did point out that I would never use it for such thing after wards in the sentence....Anyway enough spam we can argue for days without result.